# Database query in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code:

```
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MessagesHelper> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessagesHelper>()
                    .setQuery(mFetchingMessages, MessagesHelper.class)
                    .build();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessagesHelper, Chat.MessagesViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Chat.MessagesViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final MessagesHelper model) {
            holder.setMessage(model.getMessage());


            final String userId = getRef(position).getKey();
            final DatabaseReference mTimeReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
            Query messageQuery = mTimeReference.limitToLast(10);
            messageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    final String from_user = model.getFrom();
                    final boolean Seen = model.isSeen();
                        MessagesHelper message = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessagesHelper.class);

                    itemPos++;

                    if(itemPos == 1){

                        String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                        mLastKey = messageKey;
                        mPrevKey = messageKey;

                    }


                        if (from_user != null && from_user.equals(MessageSenderId)) {
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.mDisplayMessage.getLayoutParams();
                            params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setLayoutParams(params);
                            mTimeReference.keepSynced(true);


                            if (Seen == true) {
                                holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                                mTimeReference.keepSynced(true);

                            } else {
                                holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                mTimeReference.keepSynced(true);

                            }
                        } else {
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setTextColor(data);
                            mTimeReference.keepSynced(true);

                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.mDisplayMessage.getLayoutParams();
                            params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                            holder.mDisplayMessage.setLayoutParams(params);
                        }


                        messagesList.add(message);
                        messageList.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1);

                    }



                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public Chat.MessagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_activity_chat, parent, false);
            return new Chat.MessagesViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    messageList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

Its fetching the full data instead of only 10 and I can't understand why. Also I have ued keepSenced everywhere because everytime I restart the activity the whole thing executes again... Like

[image]

Then after a second it loads and displays properly [image]

This happens everytime I restart the activity... So how can i make the activity just reload the 10 latest ones instead of the whole data

Comment: If you want at some point to try [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a functional [Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). In a meanwhile, what is the value of `mFetchingMessages`?

Comment: DatabaseReference mFetchingMessages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId); @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can i make the activity just reload the 10 latest ones instead of the whole data?

You are getting all messages instead of only 10 because you are passing to your adapter a `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object that contains a query that has no limitations.

```
DatabaseReference mFetchingMessages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Messages")
    .child(MessageSenderId)
    .child(MessageRecieverId);
```

To solve this, you jsut need to add a `.limitToLast(10)` call like this:

```
DatabaseReference mFetchingMessages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Messages")
    .child(MessageSenderId)
    .child(MessageRecieverId);
    .limitToLast(10)
```